# Display Data based on user role in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, laravel-5.7

I am trying to fetch all the data on admin profile .On the admin page
 he want to see the requests made by all users.
 Login function for role check while sign in

```
 public function loginProcess(Request $request)
        {
            if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status'=>1])){
                if((Auth::user()->role == 'admin')){
                     return url('showallrequest');
                } else {
                    if($request->session()->has('request_cache')){
                        return $this->saveRequest($request);
                    } else {
                        return url('displayLegal');
                    }
                }
                return 'true';
            }
            return "false";
        }
```

user controller in which admin will logged-in and after login he will be redirected to the dashboard where he will see all the user's requests.

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 35px;padding-right: 35px;" >
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="background: red;border: none;"><a href="submit_query">New Request <i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-left: 10px;"></i></a></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="user_request_div">
        </div>
        <!--end .card -->
    </div>
    @endsection
@section('side_bar')
    @include('backend_template.includes.side_bar')
    @endsection
@section('jsses')
    @include('frontend_template.includes.foot')
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url:"showAllReqToAdmin",
            type:"POST",
            data:{_token:csrf_token},
            success: function (result) {
                $('#user_request_div').html('');
                console.log(result);
                for(var i = 0;i<result.length;i++){
                    if(result[i].service_package.default_price == null){
                        result[i].service_package.default_price = 0;
                    }
                    $("<div class='card'> " +
                        "<div class='card-body text-default-light' style='padding: 15px;' > " +
                            "<div class='row'>" +
                                    "<div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: left' >"+
                                    "<h4>" +result[i].user.firstname "</h4>" +
                                    "<h5>"+result[i].user.lastname"</h5>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<div class='col-md-3' style='text-align: left' >" +
                                        "<h4 style='padding: 0px'>"+result[i].request_type.aop.name+"</h4>" +
                                        "<h5>"+result[i].title+"</h5>" +
                                    "</div>" +
                                    "<div class='col-md-3' style='text-align: center'> " +
                                        "<h4>Resolution method:</h4> " +
                                        "<h5>"+result[i].service_package.title+ " (" + result[i].service_package.default_price + " SGD)" +"</h5> " +
                                    "</div>" +
                                    "<div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: center'>" +
                                        "<h4>Not yet assigned</h4>" +
                                    "</div>" +
                                    "<div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: center'>" +
                                        "<h4>New</h4> " +
                                        "<h5>"+result[i].created_at+"</h5>" +
                                    "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>").appendTo('#user_request_div');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

In this blade page I have written the code to append the data

** Route.php**

```
Route::get('showAllReqToAdmin', 'UserController@showAllReqToAdmin');
```

I am not getting any error,don't know where is the exact
 problem.

Comment: You don't see any error and any fetched data?

Comment: i have check the data in the postman it is coming in a JSON format but it not going on blade page

Comment: I'm not expert of laravel and blade templating but in ajax func `url:"showAllReqToAdmin"` is disappointing me. Is it proper value for url field?

Comment: yes it is a valid url earlier i was showing specific user data to himself but the main issue is how to check user role if he is admin or a normal user so that i can pass the data to the frontend

Comment: You have `data:{_token:csrf_token}` is'n it the way you can distinguish clients made reqs to your server? If not look for JWT token.

Comment: sorry bro ,i have no idea about the JWT,